# why GCM is not giving push notification in android device?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to android and doing a demo app for gcm push notification.

I have developed all this code and GCM push notification is coming on devices in my environment, but when I test this code in other network device gets registration id,but server side gets mismatch sender id response when sending messages to cloud.
My code is given bellow:

```
        checkNotNull(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_push_android);
    mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  " + regId);

    if (regId.equals("")) {
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            // final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    // ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email,
                    // regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                    mDisplay.setText("ffffff        " + regId);
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
    // regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    mDisplay.setText("ffffff        " + regId);
    Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====!!!!  " + regId);
}

private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
    if (reference == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException(getString(R.string.error_config,
                name));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
}
  }
```

receiver:

```
public GCMIntentService() {
    super(CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID);

}

private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
    Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = " + arg1);
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent message) {
    Bundle extras = message.getExtras();

    for (String key : extras.keySet()) {
        Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                String.format("onMessage: %s=%s", key,
                        extras.getString(key)));

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hii", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");

    // ///////////////////

    long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
            (CharSequence) message, when);
    String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
            PushAndroidActivity.class);
    // set intent so it does not start a new activity
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, (CharSequence) message,
            intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
}

@Override
protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
    return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
}
  }
```

This code has given me a registration id successfully.To test my code I have executed a java class to send message to cloud.That java class is:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    try {

        Sender sender = new Sender(
                "my server api");

        ArrayList<String> devicesList = new ArrayList<String>();

        devicesList
                .add("reg id");
        // devicesList.add("reg id");

        // Use this line to send message without payload data
        // Message message = new Message.Builder().build();

        // use this line to send message with payload data
        Message message = new Message.Builder()
                .collapseKey("1")
                .timeToLive(3)
                .delayWhileIdle(true)
                .addData("message",
                        "this text be will be seen in notification bar!!")
                .build();

        // Use this code to send to a single device
        // Result result = sender
        // .send(message,
        // "APA91bGiRaramjyohc2lKjAgFGpzBwtEmI8tJC30O89C2b3IjP1CuMeU1h9LMjKhmWuZwcXZjy1eqC4cE0tWBNt61Kx_SuMF6awzIt8WNq_4AfwflaVPHQ0wYHG_UX3snjp_U-5kJkmysdRlN6T8xChB1n3DtIq98w",
        // 1);

        // Use this for multicast messages
        MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);
        sender.send(message, devicesList, 1);

        System.out.println(result.toString() + "\n");
        if (result.getResults() != null) {
            int canonicalRegId = result.getCanonicalIds();
            if (canonicalRegId != 0) {
                System.out.println(canonicalRegId);
            }
        } else {
            int error = result.getFailure();
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
  }
```

Now the problem is I am not getting any push notification or log cat message.Thanks in advance for help.
Manifest:

sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

```
<permission
    android:name="com.sagar.gcma.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.sagar.gcma.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".PushAndroidActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_push_android" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.sagar.gcma" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>
```

Comment: post your manifest file. Maybe there is something wrong with broadcastReceiver declaration or something

Comment: There might be some problem with server side setup.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan:check out my edit

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj:I have no server part.So I just used that java class to send message.

Comment: maybe you forgot to declare GCMIntentService into your manifest file? `<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />`

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan:check out my edit.that was already done.

Comment: Does `sender.send` method returns `multicastResult` without errors? (I mean `InvalidRegistration` or something)? Just to be sure that gcm message have been succesfully sent to google clouds (registration id and etc. is correct) and problem is really with android project.

Comment: @almaz_from_kazan:My result is "MulticastResult(multicast_id=6168252412604758084,total=1,success=1,failure=0,canonical_ids=0,results: [[ messageId=0:1352286414060604%5695579a00000031 ]]"

Comment: It seems nobody can help me to find out solution even after I posted whole codes.

Comment: http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At last I found the reason.My company firewall was blocking all messages from GCM. So I just removed  firewall and able to receive messages from GCM [. Go through this link to know more about firewall issues](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html)

Hope it will help somebody in future.

Comment: Hello @chubbi
I was facing the firewall issue earlier in my organisation. I opened the ports 5258,29,30. Now I'm able to receive the regId from GCM server, but I still can't receive the push notification. PN are received on other netweork, but when I'm using organiasation's wifi n/w, PN are not received. Are there any more ports which need to open. I just don't understand, if I am able to receive regId, what can be the issue with receiving push notifications ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to ping google.com from your server. If it is not success try to investigate your server configuration.

E.g. Check you /etc/resolv.conf and see if you have:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```